Reverse proxy for K8 API server
We have several K8 clusters running in AKS, and we need static IP address for each of their API servers. I've tried several Azure services to accomplish this (Front Door, App Gateway, API Management) but they all run into issues when I try to configure the backend/origin server. The frequently complain about the lack of an SSL cert chain.
I'm trying to explore using a simple Nginx VM as a layer 4 proxy to my AKS api server but am having issues there too.
I originally had this in my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file -
stream {
    upstream k8s_servers {
        hash $remote_addr consistent;
        server example1234.hcp.eastus.azmk8s.io:443;
    }

    server {
        listen 6443;
        proxy_pass k8s_servers;

    }
}

I then edited my ~/.kube/config file and edit my cluster config to read -
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: XXXXXX
    server: https://k8-jumpbox.example.com

When I run kubectl get pods I get -
context deadline exceeded - error from a previous attempt: EOF
Can anyone help point out what I'm doing wrong or a better solution?

You can use Kubernetes services and perhaps Ingress (if you need access from outside the cluster) to obtain an IP address for a Nginx server hosted on AKS. Define a service that targets the Nginx Pod so that your Nginx server has a reliable endpoint.

This service will load balance requests across the Nginx Pods and offer a reliable internal IP address within the cluster.Use a load balancer service if you need to access the Nginx server from outside the AKS cluster. For creating a static IP address using the AKS check this.

The API Server of the private AKS cluster uses the Azure private Link service, so it needs to have a private IP address of the subnet that your private AKS cluster in.Refer to this documentation for more detailed information.

And the error message which you specified could be possibly due to unhealthy etcd which brought the api server down.Try checking the kubelet logs of the node where the pods try to schedule journalctl -u kubelet. Then cordon the node, making it UNSCHEDULE and try to deploy the Pod again and finally restart the node in a safe way for your applications, by performing a drain first which will fix this error.

@ImranPremnawaz we currently have a public AKS cluster and want to avoid the work needed to transition it to a private cluster. Also we were looking to have the nginx server (or whatever solution we use) live outside of the cluster so we could reach the AKS api server should we have an issue with the cluster itself. Again we just need a solution that gives us a static IP for our api server.

To Provide a static IP address for your AKS API server, you can also try using an Azure application gateway with a static IP address. This service provides web traffic load balancer with many features like URL based routing and you can configure it to be a reverse proxy for your AKS API server. Refer to this documentation.

Also you can assign a Public IP address  to AKS and please refer to this.To ensure you don't lose your PIP, keep that in a separate Resource Group from the Resource Group that contains resources that are volatile that may be deleted often.

This is what I ended up settling on. This answer helped point me in the right direction.
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

events {}

stream {
    # Define the upstream servers
    upstream foo_upstream_443 {
        hash $remote_addr consistent;
        server foo.hcp.eastus.azmk8s.io:443;
    }

    upstream foo_upstream_6443 {
        hash $remote_addr consistent;
        server foo.hcp.eastus.azmk8s.io:6443;
    }

    upstream bar_upstream_443 {
        hash $remote_addr consistent;
        server bar.hcp.eastus.azmk8s.io:443;
    }

    upstream bar_upstream_6443 {
        hash $remote_addr consistent;
        server bar.hcp.eastus.azmk8s.io:6443;
    }

    map $ssl_server_name $backend_443 {
        foo.example.com foo_upstream_443;
        bar.example.com bar_upstream_443;
    }

    map $ssl_preread_server_name $backend_6443 {
        foo.example.com foo_upstream_6443;
        bar.example.com bar_upstream_6443;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        proxy_pass $backend_443;
        proxy_timeout 120s;
        proxy_ssl on;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/example.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/example.key;
    }

    server {
        listen 6443;

        proxy_pass $backend_6443;
        proxy_timeout 120s;
        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_ssl on;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/example.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/example.key;
    }
}

